# Issue with global variable in class

Tags: c++, arduino

With the following code, it works "correctly."  Meaning it creates the foot instance of WalkerJoint.

```cpp
#include <WalkerJoint.h>

class WalkerLeg { 
  //WalkerJoint foot;
  // if this is uncommented and the below is reversed it fails

  public:
    WalkerLeg();
    void initLeg();
};

WalkerLeg::WalkerLeg(void) {
  WalkerJoint foot(2,3,4,5,6);
  //foot(2,3,4,5,6);
  //if uncommented with above it fails
}

void initLeg() {
  Serial.print("leg init\n");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {}
  // wait for Serial comms to become ready
}

void loop() {
  int bom=0;
  WalkerLeg frontLeft;
  bom=0;
  while(bom++<100000){}
  exit(0);
}
```

However, I need `foot` to be global so other methods can use it. When I move its declaration into the Class definition it gives the following error:

```
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/WalkerLeg.cpp/WalkerLeg.cpp.ino: In constructor 'WalkerLeg::WalkerLeg()':
WalkerLeg.cpp:14: error: no matching function for call to 'WalkerJoint::WalkerJoint()'
 WalkerLeg::WalkerLeg(void)
                          ^
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/WalkerLeg.cpp/WalkerLeg.cpp.ino:14:26: note: candidates are:
In file included from /Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/WalkerLeg.cpp/WalkerLeg.cpp.ino:1:0:
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WalkerJoint.cpp/WalkerJoint.h:23:3: note: WalkerJoint::WalkerJoint(int)
   WalkerJoint(int); //for using analog inputs
   ^
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WalkerJoint.cpp/WalkerJoint.h:23:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WalkerJoint.cpp/WalkerJoint.h:22:3: note: WalkerJoint::WalkerJoint(int, int, int, int, int)
   WalkerJoint(int, int, int, int, int);
   ^
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WalkerJoint.cpp/WalkerJoint.h:22:3: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 0 provided
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WalkerJoint.cpp/WalkerJoint.h:17:7: note: constexpr WalkerJoint::WalkerJoint(const WalkerJoint&)
 class WalkerJoint
       ^
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WalkerJoint.cpp/WalkerJoint.h:17:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WalkerJoint.cpp/WalkerJoint.h:17:7: note: constexpr WalkerJoint::WalkerJoint(WalkerJoint&&)
/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WalkerJoint.cpp/WalkerJoint.h:17:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
WalkerLeg.cpp:18: error: no match for call to '(WalkerJoint) (int, int, int, int, int)'
     foot(2,3,4,5,6);
                   ^
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'WalkerJoint::WalkerJoint()'
```

Comment: `WalkerJoint foot(2,3,4,5,6);` creates a local variable that immediately goes out of scope. If you have a member variable that does not have a default constructor then you must initialize it in the initializer list. Your terminology is also a bit confusing. If the variable is a regular member variable then every instance of the class has a different variable, and if it's static it is shared across all instances of the class but must be initialized differently.

Comment: Sorry for the mix of terminology.   I understand that the WalkerJoint foot(2,3,4,5,6) goes out of scope, which is the problem.   I thought that if I included it at the top (see my first commented line) that it would allow it to be available to all methods in the class?

Comment: @RetiredNinja, based on your comment I added static to the first commented line and it seemed to improve the situation.   But now gives the       '/Users/bin/Documents/Arduino/WalkerLeg.cpp/WalkerLeg.cpp.ino: In constructor 'WalkerLeg::WalkerLeg()':
WalkerLeg.cpp:18: error: no match for call to '(WalkerJoint) (int, int, int, int, int)'
     foot(2,3,4,5,6);
                   ^
exit status 1
no match for call to '(WalkerJoint) (int, int, int, int, int)''

Comment: @RetiredNinja... thank you.   I kept looking at your comment and searching  / playing and got it.   I added the static declaration and then     WalkerJoint WalkerLeg::foot(2,3,4,5,6);     and that did the trick   Thanks!